# Developers: How to control Chrome Web Store Listing?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I have successfully published an app on the Chrome Web Store.

How would I change the listing area where it says "from [URL]" to "from The Ultimate Apps"?

Listing:
[image: listing]

Dashboard settings:
[image: item]

Item settings:
[image: dashboard]

Comment: At the bottom of your dashboard.

Comment: I don't think you can override it if you use "verified site" setting.

Comment: So, what setting should I use?

Comment: If you badly need the name, you need to select "None" in the website list. But this will break some functionality (e.g. inline installs)

Comment: When I do that, it gives me the following error message "Please fix the following errors:
The web_url of this hosted web app is not owned by the developer.
The official website was not valid."

Comment: Then it's completely impossible for hosted apps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can enter a custom name if you select the "official item for a website" setting for a store item.

It's either a verified site or the name defined in account settings in the dashboard.
If you badly need the name, you need to select "None" in the website list on the item editing screen. But this will break some functionality (e.g. inline installs, and it's impossible for web apps)

Even Google's own extensions and apps do not bend that rule, i.e. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-forms/jhknlonaankphkkbnmjdlpehkinifeeg

Comment: Where can I change the "official item for a website" setting?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can edit it in the Developer Dashboard. Under "Publisher Account Settings", in "Edit publisher display name:". If you have any further concerns, please feel free to reach out to me.

Comment: I have the display name as "The Ultimate Apps" and it still displays a URL. http://geocities.ws/radar/chrome.png

Comment: I think you should make some changes under "Edit"-"Website"-"Verify that this is an official item for a website you own". Maybe you could send the screen shot of your settings about that.

Comment: It won't let me list multiple websites geocities.ws/radar/website.png